# How to extract dictionary from JSON data from API? I tried some solutions from Stackoverflow

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract the data. I tried many solutions from Stackoverflow, but I failed to extract `state_id` and `state_name`. I know many similar questions have been answered but I am not able to do it.

Here you can get the json data:

```
import requests
import json

my_headers = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36 RuxitSynthetic/1.0 v10151387278 t38550 ath9b965f92 altpub cvcv=2'
response = requests.get("https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states",headers = {'User-Agent':my_headers})

values=json.loads(response.text)
```

It's output is like:

```
{'states': [{'state_id': 1, 'state_name': 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'}, {'state_id': 2, 'state_name': 'Andhra Pradesh'}, {'state_id': 3, 'state_name': 'Arunachal Pradesh'}, {'state_id': 4, 'state_name': 'Assam'}, {'state_id': 5, 'state_name': 'Bihar'}, {'state_id': 6, 'state_name': 'Chandigarh'}, {'state_id': 7, 'state_name': 'Chhattisgarh'}, {'state_id': 8, 'state_name': 'Dadra and Nagar Haveli'}, {'state_id': 37, 'state_name': 'Daman and Diu'}, {'state_id': 9, 'state_name': 'Delhi'}, {'state_id': 10, 'state_name': 'Goa'}, {'state_id': 11, 'state_name': 'Gujarat'}, {'state_id': 12, 'state_name': 'Haryana'}, {'state_id': 13, 'state_name': 'Himachal Pradesh'}, {'state_id': 14, 'state_name': 'Jammu and Kashmir'}, {'state_id': 15, 'state_name': 'Jharkhand'}, {'state_id': 16, 'state_name': 'Karnataka'}, {'state_id': 17, 'state_name': 'Kerala'}, {'state_id': 18, 'state_name': 'Ladakh'}, {'state_id': 19, 'state_name': 'Lakshadweep'}, {'state_id': 20, 'state_name': 'Madhya Pradesh'}, {'state_id': 21, 'state_name': 'Maharashtra'}, {'state_id': 22, 'state_name': 'Manipur'}, {'state_id': 23, 'state_name': 'Meghalaya'}, {'state_id': 24, 'state_name': 'Mizoram'}, {'state_id': 25, 'state_name': 'Nagaland'}, {'state_id': 26, 'state_name': 'Odisha'}, {'state_id': 27, 'state_name': 'Puducherry'}, {'state_id': 28, 'state_name': 'Punjab'}, {'state_id': 29, 'state_name': 'Rajasthan'}, {'state_id': 30, 'state_name': 'Sikkim'}, {'state_id': 31, 'state_name': 'Tamil Nadu'}, {'state_id': 32, 'state_name': 'Telangana'}, {'state_id': 33, 'state_name': 'Tripura'}, {'state_id': 34, 'state_name': 'Uttar Pradesh'}, {'state_id': 35, 'state_name': 'Uttarakhand'}, {'state_id': 36, 'state_name': 'West Bengal'}], 'ttl': 24}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary is actually quite simple. We have the key `states`, and it's value is a list containing sub dictionaries. If we iterate through this list we can easily index `state_id` and `state_name`. Now I don't know how you want to store this gathered data, so I assumed it would be best to put each group of `"state_id" & "state_name"` in a tuple.

```
data = {'states': [{'state_id': 1, 'state_name': 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'}, {'state_id': 2, 'state_name': 'Andhra Pradesh'}, {'state_id': 3, 'state_name': 'Arunachal Pradesh'}]}
gathered = [(info['state_id'],info['state_name']) for info in data['states']]
```

output

```
[(1, 'Andaman and Nicobar Islands'), (2, 'Andhra Pradesh'), (3, 'Arunachal Pradesh')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Actually, I want to implement a dropdown menu on my webpage where I would be displaying state_name and user selecting a state will be linked  to state_id which would be used somewhere else in the program. Do you have any suggestions on it?

Comment: no sorry. I don't deal with front end cause im dumb. But good luck!